# Why Redash SQL query does not end？

Tags: mysql, redash

I have installed the Redash, I created the MySQL connection on the web and tested it, but when I was executing on the Redash query SQL page, I found that the request was always sent, no data returned.
[this is redash sql query image execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO7LP.png)

Comment: Same problem I am also facing for Postgresql

Comment: view http://localhost:9001/ and post back what you see

Comment: Assuming you are running in Docker than we have the same issue and we found this as resources issue.
we were assigning low resources to the worker containers where our db is holding a large amount of data. Increased the CPU resource done the work previous CPU resource was 0.3 now it is 0.5 and it is working fine and for redash server, we assigned 1 CPU to server. It is now stable.